# Xcode 11 - App Icons - invalid image path

Tags: ios, xcode, cfbundleicons

I am trying to upload my app to App Store Connect.
I know this question has been asked before, 
but I tried every solution I could find for days without success.

Here is the error message:

```
ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."

ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon20x20'"

ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon29x29'"

ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon40x40'"

ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon50x50'"

ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon57x57'"

ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon60x60'"

ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon72x72'"

ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon76x76'"

ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon83.5x83.5'"
```

I copied and pasted app icons from [appicon.co](https://appicon.co): [AppIcon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idxzj.jpg)

My Info section (info.plist): [Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktLR3.jpg)

My General section: [General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Ecq.jpg)

I already tried deleting and recreating the app icon and asset catalog multiple times.
I also tried using the Legacy Build System. App icon does show up in simulators and in Xcode. The problem only occurs when I try to upload the app to App Store Connect. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: well in your asset, the moment you place those icons in their respective location i.e. 60x60, it will inform you if the icon is actually that size. you just need to provide all the icons with the necessary dimension

Comment: @Joshua I already filled all of the spots (https://imgur.com/sPeyaPP). Is there any other place I need to add the icons?

Comment: I'm a bit unsure about this one tbh. do you have different targets (dev/prod)? and app icons source are properly set?

Comment: @Joshua nope it's one target. I checked Target Membership.

Comment: And app icon source is correctly set (https://imgur.com/PyUzDAn)

Comment: are you using asset catalog for icons or another ?

Comment: @Atmaram I have multiple asset catalog, but one app icon. Currently, I have trouble with app icon in the asset catalog not correctly uploading to App Store Connect

Comment: @coder1234 have you done the following........ If your application is using asset catalogs to manage its icons, verify that you have removed all icon-related keys from your application's information property list.

If your application is not using asset catalogs to manage its icons, verify that all images referenced by the CFBundleIcons key in the application's information property list are present and are associated with the application target.

Comment: @Atmaram I already removed Icon Files and CFBundleIcons~Ipad from my info.plist (https://imgur.com/uRelOei)

Comment: have you checked the resolution of that image? and Format .png or ?

Comment: @Atmaram Yep I created my icons from appicon.co and it automatically resizes the icons. They are all in png format.

Comment: I finally figured it out. The image was the problem for some reason. When I switched the image, it suddenly worked. Idk why...

Answer (score 8):

i have the same issue, the xcode error was the same, my problem was an extrange png format used to create the icons, i use and online converter to recreate the png and the online service https://appicon.co/ to generate the xcassets folder, after this change the xcode 11.3 can upload the app to app store without problems.

Comment: Same with me. Please People should avoid that website.

Comment: Sent a whole day building failed archives. Glad I found your answer and generated new icons from https://appiconmaker.co/. Thanks!

Comment: Same issue. I changed back to my previous png file and it started to work again so I think there was an issue with my png file.

Comment: i am having the same issue. What's wrong with https://appicon.co/ website.